# A game concerning Sudoku

Tags: combinatorics, sudoku

We (me and you) start with a blank $9\times 9$ blank square (as an empty Sudoku) and I fill the first three rows legally according to Sudoku rules. Is it always possible that you complete the Sudoku with this given three rows?

Comment: I voted you up because I think it's a good question. I think you might want to explain what you already did to find the answer, where you stand and so on to dissuade people from downvote.

Comment: I will presume you read Felgenhauer and Jarvis, then, since this is almost exactly what they do.

Comment: You might get a better response if you explicitly name the paper and request an explanation of (their justification of) the combination counting process.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Suppose you filled the first three rows according to Sudoku rules, let a1, a2, a3 be the 3x1 vectors in the top-left block; b1, b2, b3 be the next three 3x1 vectors in the top-middle block; and c1, c2, c3 be the last three 3x1 vectors in the top-right block.
Then consider:

\begin{array}{|ccc|ccc|ccc|}
\hline | & | & | & | & | & | & | & | & |\\
 {\vec{a}_{1}} &  {\vec{a}_{2}} &  {\vec{a}_{3}} &  {\vec{b}_{1}} &  {\vec{b}_{2}} &  {\vec{b}_{3}} &  {\vec{c}_{1}} &  {\vec{c}_{2}} &  {\vec{c}_{3}}\\
| & | & | & | & | & | & | & | & |\\
\hline  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & \\
 & ? &  &  & ? &  &  & ? & \\
 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & \\
\hline  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & \\
 & ? &  &  & ? &  &  & ? & \\
 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & \\
\hline \end{array} and fill it with\begin{array}{|ccc|ccc|ccc|}
\hline | & | & | & | & | & | & | & | & |\\
 {\vec{a}_{1}} &  {\vec{a}_{2}} &  {\vec{a}_{3}} &  {\vec{b}_{1}} &  {\vec{b}_{2}} &  {\vec{b}_{3}} &  {\vec{c}_{1}} &  {\vec{c}_{2}} &  {\vec{c}_{3}}\\
| & | & | & | & | & | & | & | & |\\
\hline | & | & | & | & | & | & | & | & |\\
 {\vec{a}_{2}} &  {\vec{a}_{3}} &  {\vec{a}_{1}} &  {\vec{b}_{2}} &  {\vec{b}_{3}} &  {\vec{b}_{1}} &  {\vec{c}_{2}} &  {\vec{c}_{3}} &  {\vec{c}_{1}}\\
| & | & | & | & | & | & | & | & |\\
\hline | & | & | & | & | & | & | & | & |\\
 {\vec{a}_{3}} &  {\vec{a}_{1}} &  {\vec{a}_{2}} &  {\vec{b}_{3}} &  {\vec{b}_{1}} &  {\vec{b}_{2}} &  {\vec{c}_{3}} &  {\vec{c}_{1}} &  {\vec{c}_{2}}\\
| & | & | & | & | & | & | & | & |
\\\hline \end{array}

Note the rest of the blocks are just permutations of the columns of the blocks above. It is done in a way so that in each block, we have all 1-9 numbers, since the first three rows are Sudoku-satisfied. And each column will also have 1-9, because we used the top three blocks to make the columns. Lastly, the rows are all satisfied with 1-9, because they are just the same rows as the first three rows except permuted again.

By way of an example, consider this:

\begin{array}{|ccc|ccc|ccc|}
\hline 5 & 3 & 4 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 1 & 2\\
6 & 7 & 2 & 1 & 9 & 5 & 3 & 4 & 8\\
1 & 9 & 8 & 3 & 4 & 2 & 5 & 6 & 7\\
\hline  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & \\
 & ? &  &  & ? &  &  & ? & \\
 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & \\
\hline  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & \\
 & ? &  &  & ? &  &  & ? & \\
 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & \\
\hline \end{array}

We will fill the remaining blocks by permuting the columns of the 3x3 blocks directly above it cyclically:

\begin{array}{|ccc|ccc|ccc|}
\hline 5 & 3 & 4 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 1 & 2\\
6 & 7 & 2 & 1 & 9 & 5 & 3 & 4 & 8\\
1 & 9 & 8 & 3 & 4 & 2 & 5 & 6 & 7\\
\hline 3 & 4 & 5 & 7 & 8 & 6 & 1 & 2 & 9\\
7 & 2 & 6 & 9 & 5 & 1 & 4 & 8 & 3\\
9 & 8 & 1 & 4 & 2 & 3 & 6 & 7 & 5\\
\hline 4 & 5 & 3 & 8 & 6 & 7 & 2 & 9 & 1\\
2 & 6 & 7 & 5 & 1 & 9 & 8 & 3 & 4\\
8 & 1 & 9 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 7 & 5 & 6
\\\hline \end{array}

Comment: This looks correct, good job bonsoon =) To clarify for the viewers, his $a_1$ vector for example is of the form $a_1 = \begin{pmatrix}a_{11}\\a_{12}\\a_{13}\end{pmatrix}$

Comment: Thanks =) I will try to clarify it.

Comment: Wow awesome job mate !

Comment: Nice. I wonder if there's a way to finish that doesn't have so much structure. You could always permute rows $4-6$ and $7-9$ but that would still leave lots of clues about how it was built.